# java - How to add zeros to an int until this int lenght equals the int2 lenght?

Tags: java, math

I don't know almost nothing about java integers.
I have an updater and i want the number 2.3.1 be smaller than 2.4.
I'm trying this but no success:

```
private Integer versionLenghtCorrector(Integer version1, Integer version2) {
    for (String version = version1.toString(); version.length() < version2.toString().length(); version = version + "0") {
        return Integer.parseInt(version);
    }
    return 0;
}
private void start() {
// End of Update code.
        Integer uVersion = versionLenghtCorrector(Integer.parseInt(updateVersion.replaceAll("\\.", "")),
                Integer.parseInt(pluginVersion.replaceAll("\\.", "")));
        Integer pVersion = versionLenghtCorrector(Integer.parseInt(pluginVersion.replaceAll("\\.", "")),
                Integer.parseInt(updateVersion.replaceAll("\\.", "")));
        if (uVersion > pVersion) {
            this.checkResult = UpdateCheckResult.AVAILABLE;
        } else {
            this.checkResult = UpdateCheckResult.NOT_FOUND;
        }
}
```

Comment: Why `return Integer.parseInt(version);` is in `for` loop?

Comment: ooo sorry I'm a little noob in for loops, did not know that return could not stay there.

Comment: If you want `2.3.1` to be smaller than `2.4` (and smaller than `2.11`), then you should implement your own `Comparator<String>`.

Comment: @ChristianoRangel `return` can stay there, but it returns immediately on the first iterated value, and will never continue the loop, so what's the *point* of the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static int addZeros(int valueToAddZeros, int valueToCompare){
    while(String.valueOf(valueToCompare).length() > String.valueOf(valueToAddZeros).length()){
        valueToAddZeros = valueToAddZeros * 10;
    }
    return valueToAddZeros;
}
```